# How can I formalize key value stores with set theory?

Tags: ds.data-structures, ct.category-theory, db.databases, set-theory

I'm currently developing a simple key-value NoSQL store and want to build its formal model. I'm interested in knowing if there some work about formalization of key-value stores outside of category theory? I want to use some more simple and lightweight mathematics for the mathematical description of key-value stores. Set theory looks like it might offer some possibilities.

Comment: It seems your question is not *research level* and would be better suited for cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Are you saying that you wish formalization that excludes Category Theory?

Comment: @ouflak Yes, exactly. I want a more simple model without category theory. I `feel` that set theory will be enough for this, but couldn't find any helpful articles

Comment: Oddly enough, I can't think of a nice introduction to various ways to specify such things. One thing you could do is to start by looking at what SMTLIB does for "arrays" (which are really maps/dictionaries) http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/logics.shtml E.g., http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories/ArraysEx.smt2

Comment: Key value store is quite simple. Why do you need a formal mathematical model? What would you expect of such a model? Why do you exclude category theory? And are you hinting that there *is* a formal model for key value store based on category theory? By key-value store, do you include replicated data types, such as `set`, `stack`, `queue`, and so on? (Sorry for so many questions.)

Comment: @cody, in the future, if recommending CS.SE, please remind them not to cross-post (as cross-posting is forbidden by site rules).  You can suggest they delete and re-ask or flag for moderator attention and ask the moderators to migrate it.  Thank you!

Comment: @hengxin Thanks for the feedback.I think category theory is too heavy for such kind of storage. I expect from it something like relational data model do for relational database. We all use key-value stores but there is no formal model of it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not say *why* you want a formalization, but presumably you want to *do* things with it, for instance prove properties of dictionaries and operations on them. In fact, your question can be understood in two ways: you want a *mathematical description* of dictionaries, or you want a *computer formalization* of dictionaries.

For a computer formalization have a look at the Coq standard library module [FMaps](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/coq/stdlib/Coq.FSets.FMaps.html), and if someone can find something better, please post it in the comments or just edit this question.

For a mathematical description all you have to note is that a dictionary is the same thing as a mapping with a finite domain. That is, if we have a dictionary (using Python style syntax):

```
d = { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 3, 'c' : 2 }
```

that is the same thing as a map $d$ whose domain of definition is the set $\{a, b, c\}$ and is defined as:
$$ d(a) = 1, \quad d(b) = 3, \quad d(c) = 2.$$
So now you can take any mathematical description of a map and use that. In set theory we would say that $d$ is the set of ordered pairs
$$\{(a,1), (b,3), (c,2)\}.$$

Comment: NoSQL database -- glorified hash table:-)